# Is it possible to use Apple's ARKit to measure the length and width of an individual's foot to estimate shoe size?

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality, arkit, measure

Disclaimer: I'm a product designer, so I'm not too technically literate in terms of AR.

Is there a way to use the iPhone's camera to measure the length and width of an individual's foot to estimate their shoe size? Most sizing charts seem to estimate shoe size based on (A) heel-to-toe distance and (B) foot width (i.e. wide-feet). Doing some of my own research, I found that Apple allows developers to use their ARKit to measure the distance from one point to another (similar to their [Measure](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102468) app).

A few follow-up questions I have:

1. How accurate is the iPhone's ability to measure distance? Specifically for objects the length of a human foot (I believe the average length of a human-foot is ~10 inches).
2. Are there factors that affect the iPhone's ability to measure distance? I'm assuming the position and steadiness of the camera, the resolution of the camera, and the foreground and background contrast between the foot and the floor are factors. Anything else?

I haven't really tried implementing this myself, but curious to know about the technical feasibility.